# TeamCity 10 NuGet Feed slow indexing

Tags: performance, nuget, teamcity, octopus-deploy

Upgraded to TeamCity 10 last week and we are now experiencing problems with our build/deployment pipeline. We are using TeamCity with the internal NuGet Feed and Octopus Deploy. A typical build creates x number of nupkg, publishes to the internal TeamCity feed, creates a new Octopus Deploy release and deploys to a preprod environment. However after upgrading, the nupkg in the TC feed are not indexed at the time of deployment. Viewing the build log, each artifact is indexed at the end of each build step. However it seems that TC10 is a bit slower at this, than TC9.

Anyone experience this? Besides publishing to Octopus Deploy's internal feed, can I tweak this behavior?

Specs: VM, 4 cores, 6GB ram, JVM at 40%
Artifact folder: 172GB, 240K files, 90K folders.

Additional information:

CPU load seems to have changes drastically after the upgrade.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you please capture several thread dumps on rinnung server and while nuget packages are being published and send them to me via e-mail (evgeniy dot koshkin as jetbrains dot com) or create an issue in the tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/TW

Comment: I've created an incident -> https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-46397